# Extracting original email and remove email alias in emails

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the primary email from aliases, for example, I have the following examples and I need to normalize them.

1. from "test.me@email.com" to "testme@email.com"
2. from "test+me11@email.com" to "test@email.com"
3. from "test.me.123+22@email.com" to "testme123@email.com"
4. from "test+123@email.com" to "test@email.com"

I wrote a SQL statement on bigquery but got an error that says "Third argument in SUBSTR() cannot be negative"

```
SELECT  TRANSLATE(SUBSTR('test+123@email.com', 1, INSTR('test+123@email.com', '+')-1),'+.', '') ||'@' || SUBSTR('test+123@email.com', Instr('test+123@email.com','@')+1)
```

Any ideas or suggestions for the above or ideas for useing regex_replace instead

Thanks

Comment: After "I have the following emails", you show a list with something different than email addresses (because `>` is not a valid character in an email address).  Please [edit] you question an let us know what you do mean with "A > B" , where both A en B are valid email addresses

Comment: I edited the question and I mean by A>B
A (email contain aliases)
B (email without alaises)

Comment: You are changing the email addresses, not normalizing them.  The email address  "abc.def@example.com" is a different address than "abcdef@example.com" (and not necessarily an alias of it )

Comment: you are right, I should have been more clearer, for example, if it is a Gmail then dots don't matter and I want to this work if it is gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select email, 
  regexp_replace(email, r'([^+@]+)+?([^@]*(.*))', r'\1\3') original_email
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case if for some reason you want dots to be removed - use below

```
select email, original_email,
  format('%s@%s', 
    replace(split(original_email, '@')[offset(0)], '.', ''), 
    split(original_email, '@')[offset(1)]
  ) with_stripped_dots
from your_table, 
unnest([regexp_replace(email, r'([^+@]+)+?([^@]*(.*))', r'\1\3')]) original_email
```

with output

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhail that is exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try regex but I am not sure whether the performance is good or bad.

```
select CONCAT(REGEXP_EXTRACT("test.me+123@email.com", r'([\w\.]+)'), REGEXP_EXTRACT("test.me+123@email.com", r'(@[\w\.]+)'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to replace `+` and `.` characters by noting (``) using:

```
TRANSLATE(SUBSTR('test+123@email.com', 1, INSTR('test+123@email.com', '+')-1),'+.', '')
```

This is not working because the second and third parameter using TRANSLATE() should have equal length.

Maybe you want to do (for the part before the `@`):

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(LEFT('test+123@email.com',INSTR('test+123@email.com','@')-1),'+',''),'.','')
```

Comment: Thanks, that is correct, I also need to remove any character after the plus sign